# Google People API don't remove contact from "starred" contactGroup

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-people-api

When try to remove contact from my "starred" contact group, I receive response 200  {} , but contact is still in the group [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAOpd.jpg).
I'm using contactGroups.members.modify, who work for all other group(delete and add), also work for adding a contact to starred, but dont work for remove. 
Is anyone have the same problem or it is a bug in People API?

Comment: This is a [confirmed](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/73857746) bug in the API and they are working on a fix.